# Trying to write a code that outputs a checkerboard in C

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I'm trying to write a code that outputs a checkerboard type effect with astericks by using for loops. I cant seem to get it to work. Here's my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{   
   int a;
   int b;

   for(a=1; a<=10; a+=2)
   { 
      printf("* * * * * * * * * *");
   }

   for (b=2; b<=10; b+=2)
   { 
    printf(" * * * * * * * * * ");
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: Care to explain the logic behind your code?

Comment: You might consider starting with code that actually compiles. You're missing a few `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are printing all the odd lines and then all the even lines of your check board. moreover you miss the carriage return. you could try with one loop only.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main (void) 
  {   

     for(int a=1; a<=10; a+=2)

     {   
       printf("* * * * * * * * * *\n")
       printf(" * * * * * * * * * \n") 
     }

     return 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to alternate each row

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {   
    int a;

    for(a=1; a<=10; a+=2) { 
        printf("* * * * * * * * * *\n");
        printf(" * * * * * * * * * \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a single loop and `a % 2` to alternate between your 2 types of lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{   
  for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a += 1)
  { 
    if (a % 2 == 0)
      printf(" * * * * * * * * * \n");
    else
      printf("* * * * * * * * * *\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a % 2` is quite costly compared to `a & 1` (or `!(a & 1)` to match the even check).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Compilers nowadays will optimize `x%2`, there's is no real-world difference, and arguably for a beginner the modulus method is clearer than using the binary operator

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to this, trying to keep it as simple as possible

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    // We want 10 checkerboard lines, so we iterate from 0 through 9
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; ++a) {
        // We want to change the pattern any other line, an easy way to do this is to 
        // branch on whether the iterator index, a, is even (a%2 = 0), or odd (a%2 != 0).
        if(a%2){
            // If a is odd we print the shifted pattern, with a newline
            printf(" * * * * * * * * * \n");
        }else {
            // if a is even, we print the normal pattern
            printf("* * * * * * * * * *\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong with printing a fixed-size board, why limit yourself to output a *string-literal*? Computers are about solving problems in a flexible way. What if instead of wanting 9-rows of 10/9-asterisk, you wanted to double the size of the board? Or, add one more column and two rows? You would be stuck changing your string literals an loop conditions.

Let the computer handle figuring out what to print based on the simple input of the number of rows? Now the number has to be an odd number, so you get to decide to add one or subtract one if an even number of row are entered, but other than that, write an algorithm that handles the rest. It takes little extra effort, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 9
#define COLS ROWS

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int rows = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : ROWS,
        cols = rows & 1 ? rows : (rows += 1);    /* must be odd */

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {    /* output rows */
        if ((i & 1) == 0)
            putchar ('*');
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)  /* output cols */
            fputs (" *", stdout);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should use `strtol` instead of `atoi` and do error checking on the input, and you should check that the argument given is non-negative and limit it to say 101 or something likely to fit within your terminal width/height, but those are left to you.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/checkers
* * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Double size board:

```
$ ./bin/checkers 19
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

The point being when you design your code, make it as robust and flexible as possible. Don't limit your code when you can accomplish the same thing in a way that provides a flexible solution.